# Сохранение датафрейма в excel с группировкой по столбцам

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сделать группировку(по строкам/столбцам) при записи объекта DataFrame в рабочий лист Excel, чтобы была возможность скрывать, раскрывать ячейки/столбцы.
Желательно через Pandas.
Не могу найти ничего подобного. Ссылка на мануал или книгу тоже подойдет.

Пример:

[image: Пример]

По итогу должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037054/how-to-exporting-dataframe-to-excel-sheet-with-grouping-based-in-categories

Comment: Вы должны понимать, что группировка в pandas и отображение ваших данных в excel - это две большие разницы, и не нужно их путать. так что, формируйте вопросы правильно.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, учту!